# Get resolution of video file

Tags: java, video

I need to get the resolution of a video file.

For now, I use [Jaffree](https://github.com/kokorin/Jaffree) (which is a FFmpeg/FFprobe command line wrapper)

Current code:

```java
final FFprobeResult result = FFprobe.atPath().setShowStreams(true)
                                      .setLogLevel(LogLevel.QUIET);
                                      .setInput(Path.of(videoResource.getPath()))
                                      .execute();

        
Integer width = null;
Integer height = null;

for (final Stream stream : result.getStreams()) {
    width = stream.getWidth();
    height = stream.getHeight();

    if (ObjectUtil.isNoneNull(width, height)) {
      break;
    }
}
```

This needs FFmpeg installed on the system, but I would like to have a Java native solution - but for now - I have not found a satisfying one.

I'm thankful for any recommendation/suggestion?

Addition: The preferred way would be to have a format agnostic way, but the 2 formats I'm mainly interested in are mp4 and mov.

Comment: _Any_ video? It would be considerably easier if you could restrict it to particular container formats or codecs.

Comment: What format is "video file"? Different formats write in different places so you must use Java to check the bytes according to that format's specification. You check bytes by loading some chunk of the file into an array then check array values.

Comment: The best case would be to have a format agnostic way - or at least a lib that can handle it :P - but the main formats will be mp4 and mov.